# Ethernet not working and wireless is slow

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, drivers, ethernet

I have a desktop PC that I built that I recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 next to Windows 8.1. It has an Ethernet port on the motherboard (MSI Z97S) and a wireless card in a PCI-Express slot (Asus PCE-N15).

(Here's a link to the parts in the build if that helps: http://pcpartpicker.com/p/JpQgmG)

I have tried to install the drivers for both and have only managed to get the wireless to kind of work (it is slower than when booted into windows and disconnects periodically). Not sure if I'm getting the wrong drivers or installing them wrong or what. I'm pretty new to Linux so any explanation of commands that I should do would be helpful.

Extra info:

The Ethernet works fine when booted into Windows so I know it's not a problem with the ports or cables.

ifconfig:

```
eth0  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 44:8a:5b:9a:79:91  
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
      Interrupt:20 Memory:f7400000-f7420000 

lo    Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:1705 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:1705 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:184795 (184.7 KB)  TX bytes:184795 (184.7 KB)

wlan0 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr e0:3f:49:8c:d0:b1  
      inet addr:192.168.1.100  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: 2002:4471:3e31:0:2dae:e29c:b691:d3f/64 Scope:Global
      inet6 addr: 2002:4471:3e31:0:e23f:49ff:fe8c:d0b1/64 Scope:Global
      inet6 addr: fe80::e23f:49ff:fe8c:d0b1/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:2086 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:2182 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:808352 (808.3 KB)  TX bytes:334478 (334.4 KB)
```

Comment: same problem.  did you find a fix?